# I can't change brightness on ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, 22.04, brightness

I recently set up a dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. After a few days when i switched from windows to ubuntu i found myself unable to change brightness with fn+F2 like in windows. I can't modify it in the parameters either. I tried almost everything i saw on webwsite like "10 ways to resolve your brightness issue on ubuntu" but none worked. xbacklight and xandr doesnt work. It seems that my directory `/sys/class/backlight` is empty so i can't modify the brightness this way and when i go to software and updates it says that i have no additional driver. I have a amd gpu and cpu. When i run `lspci | grep VGA` i have `04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cezanne [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] (rev c6)`.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I happen to have the exact same AMD integrated graphics on my laptop, down to the revision number (also have an Nvidia card, but the AMD graphics are what's controlling the screen 99% of the time), and also could not use the brightness controls after a fresh install of any Linux distribution, including Ubuntu.

To fix that, follow the instructions on this page: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

To add the following kernel parameter:

```
amdgpu.backlight=0
```

For reference, after completing that process (the Permanent version at the bottom of the page), there is a line in my `/etc/default/grub` file that reads:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.backlight=0"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately it didn't worked. I added  `amdgpu.backlight=0`  temporarily to my Boot parameters but nothing changed. I also noticed that i got a new error while booting linux it says  `amd_gpio AMD I0030:00: Invalid config param 0014`.

Comment: @Krat0s Wow, sorry that's really surprising given we have the exact same AMD graphics - sorry but could you just double-check that the spacing and everything is right when trying that kernel parameter (no spaces around the equals sign, the . between amdgpu and backlight) temporarily? Also FWIW the error when booting seems to be a debug message that's getting surfaced but might not indicate an actual problem: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/2723

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much. It seems that another parameters was the problem `acpi_backlight=vendor`. When i removed it and added `amdgpu.backlight=0` it worked. Thank you so much it was really annoying not being able to change the brightness.

Comment: Can confirm the Grub config change works:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.backlight=0"

My setup is AMD Ryzen 7 6800h with Radeon graphics and Nvidia RTX 3070 Mobile on Ubuntu 22.04.3.  I use Proprietary drivers nvidia-driver-535.   The source of the problem is that changing brightness with shortcut keys changed the 'brightness' file in '/sys/class/backlight/nvidia*/brightness' file instead of in the 'amdgpu_bl1' directory.  The Grub config change forces the shortcut keys to change the value in the correct 'brightness' file.  Thanks!